# How to make my sum method, which uses a for loop on a list, work correctly?

Tags: java, for-loop, calculator, indexoutofboundsexception, gpa

I am writing a program to calculate GPA and print a transcript. I am having some issues with the methods I have created to get the sum of a semesters gpa. Here's relevant code:

```
    double sumGP;
    ArrayList<Double> semesterGPs = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

```
    public void getGPs(double aGP) {
        semesterGPs.add(aGP);
    }
```

```
    public double getTotalGP() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= this.semesterGPs.size(); i++)                        
            sumGP = sumGP + this.semesterGPs.get(i);                            
        return sumGP;
```

Here is those blocks of code are used in the main method, as well as relevant main method code:

```
        Scanner letterGrade = new Scanner(System.in);
```

```
            System.out.print("Enter the letter grade recieved if the course is completed, otherwise enter null: ");
            aLetterGrade = letterGrade.next();
```

```
            if ((aLetterGrade.contentEquals("a")) || (aLetterGrade.contentEquals("A"))) {
                double aGPRecieved = 4.0;
                //gradePoints.add(aGPRecieved);
                aSemesterGrade.getGPs(aGPRecieved);
                aTotals.getGPs(aGPRecieved);
                System.out.println(aGPRecieved);

            }
```

```
aSemesterGrade.getTotalGP();
```

My for loop keeps throwing an index out of bounds error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at realGPA/realGPA.SemesterGrades.getTotalGP(SemesterGrades.java:50)
    at realGPA/realGPA.MainController.main(MainController.java:186)
```

I have already printed out the info from the ArrayList "semesterGPs", so I know the method is actually adding the info to the list, even two or three entries. I am very confused on why the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of an array is one greater than the final index (indices start at 0)

```
public double getTotalGP() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.semesterGPs.size(); i++)                        
            sumGP = sumGP + this.semesterGPs.get(i);                            
        return sumGP;
```

If an array is of `N` length, `array[N]` will trigger an index out of bounds error.

Comment: Only go up to `N - 1`. The code i provided should work.

Comment: That error must occur somewhere else. `i` is never `-1`

Answer (score 0):

In `getTotalGP`, you have `i <= this.semesterGPs.size()`. However, this will not work, since when `i == this.semesterGPs.size()`, `this.semesterGPs.at(i)` will be out of bounds. Change that condition to `i < this.semesterGPs.size()`.

Comment: Throw's the same error. Just to clarify, it's on the first iteration of the for loop that it throws the error. So even when (i) is zero it does not work.